# Heat mapping mine quakes

Tags: google-maps, graph, dictionary, dataset, generator

I am looking to create a heat map of quakes occurring in mines. My data set includes X, Y & Z coordinates as well as the energy expelled in each quake. Google has not been of much help, the closest thing I was able to find was a Google Maps tutorial which I have linked to below. I want to provide my own maps and use X, Y, Z coordinates instead of longitude and latitude. Is there anything out there that will help me generate what I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Example of data:
ID="1" X="19305" Y="-11211" Z="-599" Energy="3,0e+3"

Google tutorial: https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/visualizing/earthquakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my question is the language R.

http://www.r-project.org/